# Testing Windows Phone 8 Enterprise Applications

Tags: windows-phone-8

Can we use a self signed certificate to test the MDM Server with WP8 for distribution of sample enterprise applications as this process requires a certificate from Symantec ???

Answer (score 0):

A regular signed app installed via web / email must be correctly signed using the $299 Symantec certificate. The device checks the validity of both your cert and your dev center account prior to install (and launch?). Most MDMs will need to play by the same rules, but I've no idea if Microsoft Intune gets special treatment.